# malihu custom scrollbar plugin does not work with Electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I create a web application for people with intellectual disabilities. The scroll bar has been replaced by the 'malihu-custom-scrollbar plugin'. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
This works perfectly in normal browsers but now I want to be able to use the website on a local device without a browser but as an application via 'Electronjs'. (https://electronjs.org/)
This works perfectly except for the 'malihu-custom-scrollbar plugin'.

Here I found a possible answer: https://github.com/malihu/malihu-cus...gin/issues/473. But my knowledge of Electron does not go far enough. I don't know what to do with it.
In the main.js file of my electron folder I have the following function to go to a malihu example:

```
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  frame: false, 
  webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

 mainWindow.loadURL('http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom- scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html')

 mainWindow.on('closed', function () {

 mainWindow = null
 })
 }
```

You should see the custom scrollbars but There are only normal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
nodeIntegration: false, (was true)

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,

    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
    }
})
```